# How to read a friends facebook posts that where published through my app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api

My app is posting to the users Facebook wall whenever he/she reaches a new level. Now I'd like to display the progress of the user compared to its friends. Therefore I need to be able to read the posts of a users friends that have been made by my app. How can this be done using the Graph API?
The only answers here on SO suggest using FQL, but it seems to be discontinued.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the Scores API and the Achievements API are for, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements

I think what you're suggesting is completely undoable, because `friends_*` permissions have been revoked with the introduction of Graph API v2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The achievements API looks promising, but is unfortunately utterly unsuitable for the project I'm working on. So I tried the scores API, but although I get a positive reply from Facebook after posting, nothing is showing up - neither on the timeline nor at the activity log. This wouldn't matter if the app can read the score of the users friends. But is this possible? If so, do you have any ideas how the score posted by a friend can be read by the app?

Comment: Why is the Achievements API unusable? With the acording OpenGraph actions and self-hosted objects for each achievement it should exactly do what (I understand) you want, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/games.achieves/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects#selfhosted-creating The Scores API doesn't post to the User's timeline afaik...